# How to use / activate javascript in swift

Tags: javascript, php, ios, swift, web-services

i want ask how to activate/use javascript in swift?
my case is :

i have DB in MySQL with table : testdb with 2 coloumn Name and Message

so i create application contains name and message in swift, i want insert name and message from Swift (xcode) to MySQL using script PHP

script PHP i call from Swift is name webService.php

WebService.php :

```
 <?php

$name = isset($_GET["name"]) ? $_GET["name"] : '' ;

$message = isset($_GET["message"]) ? $_GET["message"] : '';

?>

<form action="tutorialTest.php" method="post" id="f">
<input type="hidden" name="nama" value="<?php echo($name); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="pesan" value="<?php echo($message); ?>">
</form>

<script>
function insertdata()
{   
var f = document.getElementById("f");
f.submit();

}
insertdata();
</script>
```

this script is bridge to script insert with name : tutorialTest.php

tutorialTest.php :

```
 <?php

 include 'connection.php';

 open_DB();

 $name = isset($_POST["nama"]) ? $_POST["nama"] : '';
 $message = isset($_POST["pesan"]) ? $_POST["pesan"] : '';

 $query = "INSERT INTO test(name,message) VALUES ('$name', '$message')";
 exec_Query($query);
 ?>
```

my code in Swift :

```
var kPostURL = "http://localhost/fendy/webService.php"
var kName = "name"
var kMessage = "message"

var postConnection : NSURLConnection!

func postItem(message: String, name: String){

    if (name != "" && message != ""){

        var postString = "\(kPostURL)?\(kName)=\(name)&\(kMessage)=\(message)"

        postString = postString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        println("\(postString)")

        var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: postString)!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        postConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)

    }
}
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {
    postItem(textView.text, name: nameTextField.text)

}
```

i already debug to get url, and result url is :

http://localhost/fendy/webService.php?name=Test%20DB&message=Hello%20World

in swift, value at url not inserted to db, but if you copy the url to browser like chrome and execute, is directly insert to DB.

the problem is i think is script in contains at webService.php, if you disabled javascript at browser, data can't insert to DB.

so how to activate/use javascript at webService.php so can work in swift?